# Nginx routes to wrong Angular application

Tags: angular, nginx, configuration, routes, router

I have a problem with my NGINX configuration for my Angular 10 applications.
It seems like the following block in the nginx configuration messes with all the other locations configured.

```
        location / {
                alias /var/www/html/myapp/;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
                add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        }
```

When this webapp on the root path is opened once, the other applications are not reachable without clearing the browser cache first.

the other apps are configured in a similar manner:

```
location /app2/ {
                add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
                alias /var/www/html/app2/;
                try_files $uri /$uri/ index.html =404;
        }
```

When I open http://host/app2/ after I opened app1, angular router seems to want to handle the app2 route, which results in a 404 in the root application.

What should I do? Do you know a setting that prevents this issue?
Is this a NGINX problem?

Thank you in advance!

Regards

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

make sure

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
```

is defined in server block not location block

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is already a root defined in the server block.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by declaring the second application in the angular service worker configuration ngsw-config.json.

The service worker interfered before even hitting the nginx reverse proxy.

Declaring the second application in a lazy assetGroup fixed the problem.